# Track which inbound link was clicked in google analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a website and I'm using Google Analytics.

I have widgets for popular posts, latest posts, posts list, etc...

I want to know if the user clicked on the link in the popular posts widget or the latest posts widget, for example, before getting to that post page.

I can change the link to something like:

```
example.com/post?ref=popular
example.com/post?ref=latest
example.com/post?ref=search
```

But I don't want those to be treated as different pages.

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you wanting to track individual pages getting clicked or wanting to count the number of people who are using the widgets?

Comment: There are a few options that can be used but once I have a better understanding of how you want to use the data I can provide the best solution.

Comment: What I want is simply see how many clicks will the popular posts widget get, and how many will the website search get, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are looking to simply count the number of times someone clicks on the links, then you want to use Google Analytics Event Tracking:       http://davidshawblog.com/2013/01/18/google-analytics-event-tracking/

You need to add an onclick event to your links and provide a name for them, e.g.:

```
onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Popular Posts', 'Clicked', 'Post Name']);"
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I have a question, will this still work even if the user navigates to another page instantly? (because he clicked a link obviously.)